# PHP Twitter OAuth Retweet

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have implemented Twitter OAuth in my web application, the web application currently fetches all tweets made with a specific tag referenced.

I'd like the user to be able to retweet any one of the tweets that are returned.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, point me to an example or documentation on how to retweet via OAuth and Twitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/id.format`

from http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-retweet

Answer (score 1):

Giving this url your tweet's id will use twitter's functionality to retweet.

http://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=